# i cant find the problem in palindrome recursion c

Tags: c

I have a problem with my program, in this code, I need to check if a string is a palindrome with recursion but for some reason, if the string length is even and every other char but the middle are 
similar then it should still work (like `aaaaaabCaaaaaa`)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define EMPTY_STRING -1 
    #define FALSE 0
    #define TRUE !FALSE
    #define MAX_STR_LEN 500

    int isPalindrome(char str[], int start, int end);

    int main(void)
    {
        char str[MAX_STR_LEN] = "some random words that will get over-drived like eggs, plane, chair and a young unicorn that jumps on the bad";
        int end = 0;
        int start = 0;
        printf("please enter the string you want to check: ");
        fgets(str, MAX_STR_LEN, stdin); //getting the string
        str[strcspn(str, "\n")]; //removeing the \n from the end
        end = strlen(str) - 2; //removing the null (And another char that i dont know how it got there)

        if (end == EMPTY_STRING) //checking if its an empty string, if it is then printing yes
        {
            printf("palindrome");
            getchar();
            return 0;
        }

        if (isPalindrome(str, start, end)) //checking if the string is a polindrom
        {
            printf("palindrome");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("not palindrome");
        }

        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    /*
    function gets a string and checks if its a polindrom
    input: the string, the first char index. the last char index
    return value: true if its a polindrom, false if its not
    */

    int isPalindrome(char str[], int start, int end)
    {
        int isPalindromeTrue = FALSE;

        if (str[start] == str[end]) //if the  chars are matching , continue
        {
            isPalindrome(str, start + 1, end - 1); //callingn the function again
            isPalindromeTrue = TRUE; //will be used after all itertions
        }

        return isPalindromeTrue;
    }
```

Comment: read wornings do not ignore them <source>:24:12: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]

Comment: You'll get a seg fault for `"aaaa"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this code. Here I deleted this redundant line `str[strcspn(str, "\n")];` and added a new if condition for the case of an "even" string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define EMPTY_STRING -1
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE !FALSE
#define MAX_STR_LEN 500

int isPalindrome(char str[], int start, int end);

int main(void)
{
    char str[MAX_STR_LEN] = "some random words that will get over-drived like eggs, plane, chair and a young unicorn that jumps on the bad";
    int end = 0;
    int start = 0;
    printf("please enter the string you want to check: ");
    fgets(str, MAX_STR_LEN, stdin); //getting the string
    //str[strcspn(str, "\n")]; //removeing the \n from the end
    end = strlen(str) - 2; //removing the null (And another char that i dont know how it got there)

    if (end == EMPTY_STRING) //checking if its an empty string, if it is then printing yes
    {
        printf("Yes");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    if (isPalindrome(str, start, end)) //checking if the string is a polindrom
    {
        printf("palindrome");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("not palindrome");
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
/*
function gets a string and checks if its a polindrom
input: the string, the first char index. the last char index
return value: true if its a polindrom, false if its not
*/

int isPalindrome(char str[], int start, int end)
{
    int isPalindromeTrue = FALSE;

    if (str[start] == str[end]) //if the  chars are matching , continue
    {
        isPalindrome(str, start + 1, end - 1); //calling the function again
        isPalindromeTrue = TRUE; //will be used after all itertions
    }
    if ((strlen(str) - 1) % 2 == 0) //checking if the string is even
    {
        if (str[(strlen(str) - 1) / 2 - 1] != str[(strlen(str) - 1) / 2])
        {
            isPalindromeTrue = FALSE; //will be used after all itertions
        }
    }


    return isPalindromeTrue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `isPalindrome` it is better to use a loop with `length(input)/2` iterations.  You do not need to pass the `start` and `end` as parameters in that case.

If you use recursion, you need to set the final (limit) condition.

```
if (start >= end) return TRUE;

if (str[start] == str[end]) 
    return isPalindrome(str, start + 1, end - 1); 
else
    return FALSE;
```

or, simpler:

```
return (start >= end)?
       TRUE: (str[start] != str[end])?
       FALSE: isPalindrome(str, start + 1, end - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the recursive `isPalindrome` there is no stop condition and you must check the result of the retrieving value from the inner function call

```
int isPalindrome(char str[], int start, int end)
    {    
        if(end<start)
            return TRUE;
        if (str[start] == str[end]) //if the  chars are matching , continue
            return TRUE && isPalindrome(str, start + 1, end - 1);           
        else
            return FALSE ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int isPalindrome(char str[], int start, int end)
    {
        int isPalindromeTrue = FALSE;

        if (str[start] == str[end]) //if the  chars are matching , continue
        {
            isPalindrome(str, start + 1, end - 1); //callingn the function again
            isPalindromeTrue = TRUE; //will be used after all itertions
        }

        return isPalindromeTrue;
    }
```

Consider a string like `"a12a"`

- After the 1st call `a-a` are equal so `isPalindrome` is called again with `start=1` and `end=2` for the pair `1-2`.
- `1` and `2` are different so the call returns `FALSE`. Then comes in the assigment

```
            isPalindromeTrue = TRUE; //will be used after all itertions
```

and, as the comment says, it is used for all iterations. Then the last recursion returns `TRUE` and he program fails.

#### about the code

- Check for an empty string before the call is not safe. One can call `isPalindrome` with an empty string after all.
- it is simpler to just pass the string size and not the 2 indexes
- do not pause the program. It will ruin testing with scripts.
- Use the command line and pass the strings directly.
- it is common knowledge that in `C` `0` is false. It is really an improvement define things like

```
#define EMPTY_STRING -1 
  #define FALSE 0
  #define TRUE !FALSE
```

?

#### consider this alternative

```
int isPal_r(const char* str, const size_t size)
{
    if (size < 2) return 1;  // trivial
    if (*str != *(str + size - 1))
        return 0;                       // not palindrome
    return isPal_r(str + 1, size - 2);  // try inner string
}
```

The conditions are clear:

- `size<2` means a central letter as in `"axa"` or an empty string at the end of an even sring like `"aaaa"`
- return `0` for false
- call itself again with 2 letters less, since we just compared the outer ones. And the string address in also incremented at the other end.